# Dry rub baby back ribs

Tags: baking, oven, ribs

My daughter likes dry...dry rub ribs.They come out too moist or wet when slow cooked in foil.Can I just put the rubbed ribs on a rack and cook at 200 for 5 or 6 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foil when you want to retain moisture.  Cook uncovered when you want to lose moisture.  Depending on the rib you are using, you'll want to monitor timing for desired result.